# Too much space between list items in Navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make it so the items (menu, about us, etc) are all evenly spaced out throughout the navbar and not bunched up to one side?

https://jsfiddle.net/dd19sg5x/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div>
         <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav-demo" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar">a</span>
         <span class="icon-bar">b</span>
         <span class="icon-bar">c</span>
       </button>
        <img src="images\logo.png" href="main_page.html" width=75% height=75% alt="Company Logo of Broadstairs Hotel" href="www.google.com"/>

         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container" id="bs-nav-demo">
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="top-navbar">
                 <li><a href="html\book.html">Book</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Enquire</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Facillities</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>



    <!-- Navbar stuff is done -->

        </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

My tip is to set the `.navbar-header` to a fixed width depending on your logo width and make it `position: absolute;`. I've set it to `200px;`. Than the `padding-left` of the `.navbar-collapse` will be that `200px;` After that if you have 6 menuitems, than one item should be exactly `16.666%` wide.

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/9ts0Lcxe/

Added code in css in is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-header {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 200px;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 200px;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li {
    width: 16.666%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Flex seems to be a good solution.
These two links have helped me a lot.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Your code could look like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  ul.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="nav-brand"><img src="images\logo.png" href="main_page.html" width=75% height=75% alt="Company Logo of Broadstairs Hotel" href="www.google.com"/></a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="html\book.html">Book</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Enquire</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Facillities</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Rooms</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked really well but there's now a large amount of space above the list. How do I make it all go onto one line? http://prntscr.com/f2vmqb

Comment: I guess - which is all I can do until I see the code - the logo or its wrapper has the [display property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) `block`. It should be an inline-block though. I highly recommend reading your way through the basics of CSS. Try [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/)